# Message from stored procedure to alert box in view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, alert

I am sending parameters to a stored procedure and the stored procedure return a message back, it's either a success or an error.

```
public IActionResult Index() => View();

public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file) 
{
    int cmdResponse = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@response"].Value);
            string cmdMessage = cmd.Parameters["@message"].Value.ToString();
            if (cmdResponse == 0)
            {
                con.Close();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", Json(new { status = "error", message = cmdMessage }));
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", Json(new { status = "success", message = cmdMessage }));

}
```

and here is the view with the Javascript where I try to display the message from the stored procedure in an alert box.

```
<script>

    $(function () {
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            dangerResponseMessage('btn');
        });
    });

    function dangerResponseMessage(result) {
        var url = window.rootUrl + 'Upload/Upload';

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.message);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(result.message);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that the alert box displays undefined
[image]

and when I dismiss the alert, it return the message from the stored procedure in the URL in the browser.
[image]

The cyrillic sentence in the URL is the message I am trying to display in the alert box.
[image: Correct value for cmdMessage]
The ajax call is without data, since I don't need to send anything from the view to the controller.
Any ideas as why is it showing the message in the URL and not in the alert box?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just console.log(result) to just confirm exactly what you're getting back?  If you're code in failing in 'error', then does 'result exist?  Looks like it belongs to 'success' which may also be why it's failing and showing up on the address bar.

Comment: It's a bummer when you want to help but can't post a comment, I know, I've been there :). That said, don't take it personal when this 'answer' gets down voted.

Comment: hmm, console.log print the ID of the upload button.